# javax.servlet.ServletException: org.primefaces.context.RequestContext.getCurrentInstance

Tags: maven, jsf, primefaces

I am making a `maven` project using `JSF 2.2`, `Primefaces 6.2` on Eclipse. I recieved the following error when I tried to use `<p:chips id="chips" />` that is displayed on Primefaces' [website](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/chips.xhtml):

> javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   org.primefaces.context.RequestContext.getCurrentInstance(Ljavax/faces/context/FacesContext;)Lorg/primefaces/context/RequestContext;

Even though I have removed the changes I made on my `.xhmtl` page and took it all the way back where it was running, I still receive the same error and my webpage is not running.

Here is my `pom.xml` for primefaces component:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.primefaces/primefaces -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>6.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Could that be some kind of `Eclipse - Maven`  compile error? I have cleaned, re- built the project and even deleted `.m2` file but nothing changed. All help will be appreciated.

Also here is the exception and stack trace:

> 2018-05-15T08:34:34.986+0300|Warning: StandardWrapperValve[Faces
>   Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.primefaces.context.RequestContext.getCurrentInstance(Ljavax/faces/context/FacesContext;)Lorg/primefaces/context/RequestContext;
>     at
>   org.primefaces.util.AutoUpdateComponentPhaseListener.beforePhase(AutoUpdateComponentPhaseListener.java:35)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.handleBeforePhase(Phase.java:228)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:99)     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Is there any additional stack trace for that exception? What is the actual exception details? A ServletException can happen for any number of reasons.

Comment: I have added stack trace to my question. You can find it above.

Comment: As far as I can tell version 6.2 added the method in question. Do you have an older version in your application perhaps? Perhaps in the web-inf/lib? [RequestContext 6.2](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/6.2/org/primefaces/context/RequestContext.html) and [RequestContext 6.1](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/6.1/org/primefaces/context/RequestContext.html)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell version 6.2 added the method in question. Perhaps you have an older version in your application? Check in the web-inf/lib directory. For reference: [RequestContext 6.2](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/6.2/org/primefaces/context/RequestContext.html) and [RequestContext 6.1](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/6.1/org/primefaces/context/RequestContext.html)